# How to pause music after clicking home button and after reopen app how to play music from where stopped position in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi am doing one app here if click back button then i reopen application means i need to play music from starting onwards..if click home button means i need to pause music again i reopen app means i need to play where i press home button in song middle that time onwards..i tried using below code in pause() i release sound...for back button its working, but if press home button again reopen app means app not playing any sound, i want both functionality..how to do nay one suggest me..

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;
MediaPlayer level;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    level=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.bgmusic);
    level.setLooping(true);
    level.start(); 

     b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activityyy2.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}

 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    if (level != null) {
        if (level.isPlaying()) {

            level.stop();

        }
        level.release();
        level = null;
    }
}
    }
public class Activityyy2 extends Activity {
MediaPlayer bgmusic;
Button b1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actvity2);

    bgmusic=MediaPlayer.create(Activityyy2.this,R.raw.bgmusic);
    bgmusic.setLooping(true);
    bgmusic.start(); 


      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent i=new Intent(Activityyy2.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if (bgmusic != null) {
        if (bgmusic.isPlaying()) {

            bgmusic.stop();

        }
        bgmusic.release();
        bgmusic = null;
    }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pause or stop your playback and store the current position in onPause()
2. Reopen the stream and seek to the position in onResume()

Comment: if i did like that means after clicking back button also its starting from stoped postion but i want starting postion onwards

Comment: Then you might watch for the keyPressed event and do some additional handling too.

Answer (score 0):

Store values in `Bundle savedInstanceState` in `onPause()` and get values from it in `onResume()`

Answer (score 0):

use onBackPressed and onPause something like this

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    if (level != null) {
        if (level.isPlaying()) {

            level.stop();

        }
        level.release();
        level = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    if (level != null) {
        if (level.isPlaying()) {

            level.pause();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle back button explicitly by following code:

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
      }
}
```

For homeButton, you can use this api:

```
public void  onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus){
}
```

hasFocus is the boolean value and based on focus value, you can write the logic

Comment: In case one of the answers helped you to resolve issue, please accept that so thats others can get to know the correct answer and this thread becoms useful. If not, please do post the correct answer once you resolve it. Thanks