# Detect application close/minimalize

Tags: android, android-activity

first - sorry for my English.

I just created Android app. It contains several activities and in the background of this application music is played. When user go out from app in some way (by click "back" button, home button, or in other way), then I need to stop play the music. The problem is to handle this moment. I don't know how.

Please help me,
CD

Comment: please provide some code. especially where the music starts.

Answer (score 1):

You can check when your application is in background by using :

1.

```
   public boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
    try {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
            ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
            if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(
                    context.getPackageName())) {
                     return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then in your onPause you can call this method ,and can stop the sound.
And in onRestart() you can start the sound.

2.You can override OnBackPressed() method you can stop the sound here in this method

3.Also,You can use keyEvent

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
             //Your Code here
             // You can stop the sound here also
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stop playing music `onPause()`. Start playing the music `onResume()`. But obay the guidlines stated by google: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/making-android-games-that-play-nice.html

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to do something like [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306515/how-to-pause-music-after-clicking-home-button-and-after-reopen-app-how-to-play-m/18306579#18306579)

If so then use below code..here **level** is object of mediaplayer.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onBackPressed();

  if (level != null) {
    if (level.isPlaying()) {

        level.stop();

    }
    level.release();
    level = null;
  }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();

  if (level != null) {
    if (level.isPlaying()) {

        level.pause();

    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in Android to detect when an app goes into the background. There is only callbacks for when an Activity goes to the background.

An example solution could be playing the music using a Service and in every Activity's onPause and onResume methods', inform the Service to pause/resume the music.